# ampscript Question

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, email-template, email-studio

I'm very new to ampscript and am having an issue with a snippet of ampscript showing as blank. This is what I currently have:

SNIPPET 1:

```
%%[ set @firstName = Lookup('master','first_name','email',email) 
IF @firstName == "" 
THEN set @firstName = "Friend" 
ENDIF ]%% 
Hey %%=v(@firstName)=%%, if you love someone let 'em know!
```

SNIPPET 2 (showing as blank):

```
%%[ set @smilereferralurl = Lookup('master','smile_referral_url','email',email) 
IF @smilereferralurl == "" 
THEN set @smilereferral = "Create an account to get your code." 
ENDIF]%% 
%%=v(@smilereferralurl)=%%
```

SNIPPET 3:

```
Imagine your balance of
%%[ set @smilepointsbalance = Lookup('master','smile_points_balance','email',email) 
IF @smilepointsbalance == "" 
THEN set @smilepointsbalance = "0" ENDIF ]%%  
%%=v(@smilepointsbalance)=%% + 1000 more inkbucks
```

Snippet #2 is not showing anything but the other two are populating as expected. Any and all feedback is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`@smilereferral` (sans "url" in the identifier name) is being assigned the value, but `@smilereferralurl` is what's being passed to the `v()` function. I.e., try:

```
set @smilereferralurl = "Create an account to get your code."
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend you to use [Empty()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm) to check if the string is empty, as it also checks whether it is *null*. E.g.

```
IF Empty(@smilereferralurl) THEN
```

Also, I don't see how your *email* string works, as the recipient email address normally is referenced *emailaddr*, as per this [list of personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5). Other than that, your syntax looks correct. So my theory is that *smile_referral_url* is null in your case. 
**EDIT: Mark G spotted the difference between the variable names referenced, where @smilereferral != @smilereferralurl**

Also, if all three blocks are in the same email, you use three iterations through the same data extension. I will recommend using this approach, with a single iteration, using [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm?search_text=lookup):

```
%%[ 
set @recipientrows = LookupRows('master','email',emailaddr)
IF RowCount(@recipientrows) > 0 THEN
set @recipientdata = Row(@recipientrows,1) 
ENDIF
set @firstname = Field(@recipientdata, 'first_name')
set @smilereferralurl = Field(@recipientdata, 'smile_referral_url')
set @smilepointsbalance = Field(@recipientdata, 'smile_points_balance')

IF Empty(@firstname) 
THEN set @firstname = "Friend" 
ENDIF 
]%% 
Hey %%=v(@firstname)=%%, if you love someone let 'em know!
```